# SQL OFFSET syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to increase the offset every time by 3, so I used a variable that is increased by 3 every time a button is clicked (using ajax).

However, I keep getting a syntax error when using `OFFSET`.

Is this the correct way to do it?

```
$web = "SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE catid = 9 AND state = 1 ORDER BY ordering LIMIT 0,".$_POST['limit']." OFFSET ".$_POST['limit']."";
```

limit is increased by 3 every button click, if I leave out `OFFSET`, it works, but it keeps loading all items again, instead of just 3 new items.

My error:

> There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OFFSET 3' at line 1]

Comment: besides Gordon's answer; you're open to an SQL injection here.

Comment: Like @Fred-ii- says,  [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Prefer prepared statements for SQL incection prevention. Alternatively explicitly convert $_POST['limit'] to an integer in PHP and insert that into the string. That is similar to quoting for strings, but for numbers. Anyway, I'd always propose prepared statements as best solution, since it works the same for all datatypes whatsoever.

Comment: I always use protection against SQL injection, but I first like to make the code work. So I didn't add it yet in my question. It's just a matter of adding a simple line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
 LIMIT ".$_POST['limit']." OFFSET ".$_POST['limit']."";
```

The `0` conflicts with `OFFSET`.

Comment: Great, that works. Ill accept your answer in 9 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You look like your using both limit x,x and offset X in the same query.

Try removing the offset part and just using limit X,x.

Comment: You can use both in a query. In fact offset can only be used when limit is inside a query.